# Metric Space Question: is $H(x)$ in this neighborhood?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Let the metric $d$ be defined as
$$
d(f,g) =\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f(x)-g(x)|,
$$
and let
$$
H(x) = \begin{cases} 0 \text{ if } x \leq \frac{1}{2}\\ 1 \text { if } x > \frac{1}{2} \end{cases}.
$$
Is $f(x) = x$ in $B_\frac{1}{2}(H)$ ?

**My answer**. No, because
$$
d(H(x),f(x)) = \sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f(x)-H(x)| = \frac{1}{2}.
$$
Therefore, $f(x) \not \in B_\frac{1}{2}(H)$

I am not sure if my answer is correct, and I found that it is hard to visualize this metric. Can someone helps me on this?

Comment: Your answer is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$d(H,f) \ge |H(\frac12)- f(\frac12)| = |0 - \frac12|= \frac12 $ as the sup of a set is an upper bound for it. So $f \notin B_{\frac12}(H)$ as claimed. Well done.

Answer (score 2):

This metric is actually quite easy to visualize. Draw the graph of both functions and then the largest vertical distance between $f$ and $g$ is exactly $d(f,g)$. In this case the largest distance occurs at $x = \frac{1}{2}$, so your answer is correct.